# Can't add custom rule when using the vlucas/valitron form validation package

Tags: php, validation

I've been trying to add a custom rule to the Valitron validator, but without success. The documentation is [here](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/valitron#user-content-adding-custom-validation-rules)

My own custom rule didn't work, so I tried using the simplest possible implementation with the actual example from the documentation, and the rule still doesn't trigger. Here is what I have:

```
$input = [
  'building'=>'',
  'other_building'=>''
];
Valitron\Validator::addRule('alwaysFail', function($field, $value, array $params, array $fields) {
    return false;
}, 'Everything you do is wrong. You fail.');
$v = new Valitron\Validator($input);
$v->rule('required', ['building']);
$v->rule('alwaysFail', 'other_building');
```

When I call $v->errors() it returns the 'Building required' error, but not the error message for 'alwaysFail.' I've also tried the format for just adding a custom rule for a specific field:

```
$v = new Valitron\Validator($input);
$v->rule(function($field, $value, $params, $fields) {
    return false;
}, "other_building")->message("{field} failed...");
```

If I dump out the value of $v I can see that the rule is in there, attached to other_building. But it never fails validation (I've also tried having the rule return true just to see what happens - same result). Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. It seems a bit obvious in retrospect, but I've been working on this for a couple of days. The problem is that 'other_building' is blank, and is allowed to be blank (e.g. not required). Therefore the validator is passing over it and never checking the rule. If you put in a non-blank value for 'other_building', it works. It also works if you leave it blank, but add a rule that 'other_building' is required. If you don't want the field to be required, but you also want the rule to run every time 'other_building' is in the data, even if the value is blank, you need to add an 'optional' rule, which states that "Value does not need to be included in data array. If it is however, it must pass validation."

So this works:

```
$input = [
  'building'=>'',
  'other_building'=>''
];
$v = new Valitron\Validator($input);

$v->rule('optional', ['other_building']);
$v->rule(function($field, $value, $params, $fields) {
    return false;
}, "other_building")->message("{field} failed...");
```

I guess this problem was too niche to attract any commentators, but I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else in the future.